# ESP8266 webserver does not return latest HTTP response

Tags: esp8266, web-server, http, iot

I tried getting a HTTP response from an ESP8266 which is in HTTP server mode, I am getting a response but not the latest one, response is always one command previous to that of my request to the ESP.
Also first time I don't get any response, from the nd request response start coming but previous.

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>   //ESP Web Server Library to host a web page

const char* ssid = "SpruceRND";
const char* password = "sprucernd1234";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);   // server at port 80 (http port)

//Variable to store the HTTP request
String inputString ="";
boolean stringComplete = false;
String Clientquery ="";  //for store all query params
char query_array[30];    //for store all query character
int LEDPin = 4;

void ESPserialEvent()
{
  boolean x=0;
  Serial.println("Working ESPserialevent....");
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();    // get the new byte:
    if (inChar == 2)   //check if 1st byte is 2 
    {
      x=1;
    }
    if (x == 1);
    {
    inputString += inChar;   // add it to the inputString:
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    }
    if (inChar == 3) //check if 1ast byte is 3 
    {
      stringComplete = true;
      x=0;
    }
  }
}

void  handleNew()
{
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello! SPRUCE"); //200=http status code,text/plain=content type,message
}

void handleMstring()
{
  Clientquery = server.arg("tx");    //Gets the value of the query parameter
//  Clientquery.toCharArray(query_array, sizeof(Clientquery)); // convert to chararry (buffer,length)
//  if (query_array[0] == 2 )
//  {
    Serial.println(Clientquery);
//  }
//  else
//  {
//     Serial.println("Incorrect string....");
//  }
  Clientquery="";
  ESPserialEvent();
  if (stringComplete == true)
  {  
    server.send(200, "text/plain",inputString);
    //Serial.println("Response from Mcu=" +inputString);
    //Serial.println("");
    inputString ="";
    stringComplete = false;
    //Serial.println("Buffer clear...");
  }
}

void setup(void)
{
  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //begin WiFi connection
  Serial.println("Connecting to....");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/test", handleNew);
  server.on("/senddata", handleMstring);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Web server started!");
}

void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: AT commands or esp8266 sketch? show the sketch

Comment: i don't know.How to post code

Comment: the cause of your problem is `if (stringComplete == true)` in `handleMstring`

Comment: I don't  what is the problem can you please help me. I am beginner.

Comment: It is a coding logic problem, not an Arduino problem.

Comment: one thing that produces a delay between an input and an output in any program is EOL (end of line) not being sent at the end of the command .... check that complete commands are being sent